# Updating LiveCode desktop app from the web

Tags: livecode, self-updating

How would I build a LiveCode application that can update its component stacks with newer versions from a web server? I have seen this mentioned as "easy to do" but have been unable to locate specifics on how it can be down.

Comment: The problem here is of course that HyperCard (LC's spiritual predecessor) could make classic Mac applications that would safe themselves, so people who are used to that need to relearn a bit.

Comment: @JayC I tried to edit your question but it was rejected due to too many changes. Have a look yourself and see if you can edit this question to get it reopened again http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2870787

Answer (score 4):

It's just a few lines of code. Open the stack from the server and save it to disk:

```
go stack url ("http://path/to/server/file.livecode")
set the filename of this stack to <path on disk>
save this stack
```

If you don't want to actually display the stack, you can just load it into a variable and save that to disk. Be sure to use binary if you do that:

```
put url ("http://path/to/server/file.livecode") into myVar
put myVar into url ("binfile:" & <path on disk>)
```

The second method could be reduced to a single line of script.

There's a LiveCode lesson that explains the concepts here: 
http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/78702-opening-a-stack-from-the-server